# Recursive file search in Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

On the left-side bar in Jupyter Lab, I can search for a file in the current directory

[image]

However, I have to be in the exact folder to find a file.

I would like to search for the file recursively, or alternatively search through all files in the root directory. In this example, I would like to find `file.txt` even when searching from `folder`

[image]

Can this be done?

Comment: [jupyterlab-quickopen](https://github.com/parente/jupyterlab-quickopen) might be of your interest.